# AbstractFactoryBean to get a specific bean as prototype and eager init false

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use `AbstractFactoryBean` to get a specific bean as prototype, basically each time this bean is used i want a new object get created.
I have referred spring docs and they mention that just overriding `isSingleton` is not enough and one has to implement `SmartFactoryBean` as well.

Also I dont want to eager init the bean and override `destroy` method.

But my bean is early initialzed, i.e. as soon as application start the session already started. And even after using the bean in web request, the session didn't get destroyed.

Can anyone please help

```
package com.rokitt.es.factories;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.SmartFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SparkSessionFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean<SparkSession> implements SmartFactoryBean<SparkSession> {

@Value("${spark.master}")
private String sparkMaster;

@Override
public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return SparkSession.class;
}

@Override
protected SparkSession createInstance() throws Exception {

    return SparkSession.builder().appName("{assign based on class in which injected}")
            .master(sparkMaster)
            .config(new SparkConf()
                    .set("getSparkSession.serializer", "org.apache.getSparkSession.serializer.KryoSerializer")
                    .set("getSparkSession.kryoserializer.buffer", "24mb")
                    .set("getSparkSession.rdd.compress", "true")
                    .set("getSparkSession.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom")
                    .set("getSparkSession.executor.memory", "4g")
                    .set("getSparkSession.es.batch.size.bytes", "20mb")
                    .set("getSparkSession.es.batch.size", "10000")
                    .set("getSparkSession.es.nodes", "localhost:9200"))
            .getOrCreate();
}

@Override
protected void destroyInstance(SparkSession instance) throws Exception {
    instance.stop();
}

@Override
public boolean isPrototype() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEagerInit() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isSingleton() {
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a specific Spring bean as prototype maybe lookup method would help you:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-method-injection

Prototypes are not initialized eagerly and don't support destroy methods.